# changing the starting value in ROW_NUMBER in sql

Tags: sql, ssms, partition, row-number

When I am using `ROW_NUMBER` in SQL the starting value starts from '0' but I need to start it from '00001' is it possible?

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attribute1 ORDER BY attribute2 ASC) as 'VisitCode', 
  Code1, Date, Id, PrefixCode
```

I tried
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Field) - 1 AS FieldAlias` (To start from 00001) but it's showing an error:

> 'Expecting Select or ')' '

Comment: What should be the purpose? Please show some sample data and the expected result. If you want to append some leading zeros (although I don't understand why this should make any sense), just do this. Why should it be required to change the row number's start value?

Comment: In fact `ROW_NUMBER()` already starts at 1.  What is your exact problem here?

Comment: 00001 is not a number, it is a string resulting from padding a number with leading zeros.